# Does Microsoft Security Bulletin MS11-049 affect SQL Server 2008 SP3?

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008, security

The [security bulletin](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms11-049) does not list SQL Server 2008 SP3 under affected software but it came out prior to that service pack. We are running SP3 but this issue is still showing up on a vulnerability scan. Does anyone know for sure if this is a false positive? I only found one forum post where someone said SP3 "should" include this security update.

Answer (score 1):

Scroll down to `Security Update Deployment` and open that up. Then open `SQL Server 2008`. You will see that SP3 includes this fix.

If your tool is reporting this problem because it doesn't detect the patch then one of the following is true:

- The tool is wrong.
- The tool has additional information not listed on that page.

If your tool is reporting the problem because it's using an exploit to test the vulnerability, then I would take that up with Microsoft.